# Firefox RDM Touch Simulation doesn't simulate hover?

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

When using Firefox on a mobile device, touching on an element triggers the `:hover` pseudo-class.  However, when using Firefox on a PC in Responsive Design Mode with Touch Simulation active, the `:hover` is not triggered by clicking the mouse button on the element.  If I turn off Touch Simulation, then hovering the mouse over the element will of course activate `:hover`, but isn't the point of Touch Simulation to translate mouse-inputs into their corresponding touch-events?  If touching an element on a mobile browser activates `:hover`, then shouldn't clicking the mouse in Touch Simulation also trigger `:hover`?

[Simple JSFiddle to illustrate](https://jsfiddle.net/mritty/gtcxqzb6/) - view both on PC Firefox in RDM and on mobile Firefox to see the difference.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a deficiency with Firefox RDM or with my understanding of Touch Simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `:hover` `:focus` `:active` are pseudo-classes, according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) from mozilla `:hover` matches when the user interacts with an element with a pointing device and problematic on touchscreens. We can achieve same effect `:hover` does in touchscreen using `:active` pseudo-class. Or combination of both.

As you said simulation of touch for `:hover` class is not working in Firefox. There is no promise to support it in future. Touch and pointing device worked in a very different way so its better not to use `:hover` that need the position of pointer to activate. On the other hand touch screen have no record of position before touch, so `:focus` `:active` are better alternative.

I will be happy if it does any help to you. Thanks.